# Unknown pragma when compiling OpenMP with g++

Tags: c++, g++, openmp

I am working on C++ code which contains `openmp pragmas`. While trying to compile with `g++`, I am receiving the following error message:

`ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]`

I understand that the error is from not using `fopenmp` flag with in the makefile. I have tried including the `fopenmp` flag to the `CXXFLAGS`. Still, it is not working.

Would anyone think of solutions to work around this issue?

Note: This question looks like a repeat question of similar question on same error and I have gone through and tried it too. Therefore, I would request this question not to be flagged as repeat question.

Comment: That is a warning message, no an error

Comment: @talonmies: Meaning that the `pragma` is ignored during compilation. But, I would like to include `openmp pragmas` during compilation.

Comment: Try adding `-fopenmp` to `LFLAGS` as well.  At least I have to do this when I use Qt.

Comment: Do you get the same warning or a different problem when you add `-fopenmp` to CXXFLAGS?

Comment: @Zboson: Did you mean `LDFLAGS`?

Comment: @SathishKrishnan: Can you show a minimal example for the code and the compiler invocation you are using?

Comment: @BenjaminBannier, when I use Qmake I have to do `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp`.  That's what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is warning appears if you compile OpenMP code without the `-fopenmp` flag. The `g++` man page tells us what `-fopenmp` does:

> Enable handling of OpenMP directives "#pragma omp" in C/C++ and
>      "!$omp" in Fortran.  When -fopenmp is specified, the compiler
>      generates parallel code according to the OpenMP Application Program
>      Interface v3.0 http://www.openmp.org/.  This option implies
>      -pthread, and thus is only supported on targets that have support
>      for -pthread